# How can I make this array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, trigonometry

I am trying to figure out the lengths of a house shape based on curtain points on the triangle half. for example every time I move down the long side of the triangle I would take a measurement each time having a shorter measurement than the last. I am trying to right code that will find this for me. I know that the first measurement will be equal to the height from the floor bottom to the peak of the triangle. Then each time it moves three feet down the triangle it will subtract 9 inches. However I need it to stop when it hits zero. I have set up my array like this.

```
var endwallPanelLength=[]
endwallPanelLength[1]=peakHeight;
endwallPanelLength[2]=peakHeight-peakHeightDecrease;
endwallPanelLength[3]=endwallPanelLength[2]-peakHeightDecrease;
endwallPanelLength[4]=endwallPanelLength[3]-peakHeightDecrease;
```

I know I have other things to work out for the whole code but how can I at least define these measurements in the array more efficiently.

peakHeightDecrease is just 3 * the slope

Comment: Wall of text. Summarize. What exactly is the question there? You want us to code it for you?

Comment: How can I define that variable more efficiently?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would belong more to http://programmers.stackexchange.com since it's optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
var endwallPanelLength = [peakHeight];
var i = 0;
while (endwallPanelLength[i] >= peakHeightDecrease) {
    endwallPanelLength.push(endwallPanelLength[i] - peakHeightDecrease);
    i++;
}
```

BTW, array indexes normally start at 0.

Another way is just to divide peakHeight by the the decrease:

```
var repetitions = Math.floor(peakHeight/peakHeightDecrease);
var endwallPanelLength = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= repetitions; i++) {
    endwallPanelLength.push(peakHeight - peakHeightDecrease*i);
}
```

Comment: This answer is working however it always gives me one negative value at the end?

Comment: Changed the end condition. Another way to do this is just to divide peakHeight by peakHeighDecrease to get the number of iterations. Isn't this really simple math?